# Adding A Date Picker For Mobile Project Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, datepicker, flex4.6

This is my code for my UI i am currently using, i would like to add a date picker for android into this code. The field that has the Id="datepicker" is where i am looking to add the date picker. Also i am looking to add these to the UI 
1). Print button *Prints receipt to a printer if possible or even saves the file locally*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Transaction" xmlns:components="components.*"
        viewDeactivate="callout.close()"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="PaymentMethod"/>
        <components:MyCalloutComp id="callout" height="200" close="location.text=event.data" verticalPosition="after"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            [Bindable]
            protected var total:Number = 0;

            protected function inputChangeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
            {
                var n:Number;
                total = 0;

                n = Number(input1.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;

                n = Number(input2.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;

                n = Number(input3.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;

                n = Number(input4.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;

                n = Number(input5.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;

                n = Number(input6.text);
                if (!isNaN(n))
                    total += n;
            }

]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label x="878" y="312" fontSize="18" fontWeight="bold" text="{total}"/>
    <s:Label x="17" y="15" color="#1294E7" fontSize="18" fontWeight="bold" text="Method of Payment"/>
    <s:RadioButton x="291" y="46" label="CREDIT CARD" groupName="PaymentMethod"/>
    <s:RadioButton x="11" y="46" label="CASH" groupName="PaymentMethod"/>
    <s:RadioButton x="144" y="47" label="CHECK" groupName="PaymentMethod"/>
    <s:Label x="26" y="90" text="Card Type"/>
    <s:Button x="686" y="413" width="82" label="Print"/>
    <s:Button x="800" y="413" width="96" label="Process"/>
    <s:TextArea x="25" y="175" height="38" maxChars="7"/>
    <s:Label x="25" y="159" text="Drivers License #"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input1" softKeyboardType="number" x="616" y="34" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="175"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input2" softKeyboardType="number" x="847" y="33" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="154"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input3" softKeyboardType="number" x="616" y="106" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="175"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input4" softKeyboardType="number" x="847" y="103" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="154"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input5" softKeyboardType="number" x="616" y="180" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="175"/>
    <s:Label x="638" y="17" text="Towing Charge"/>
    <s:Label x="870" y="16" text="Mileage Charge"/>
    <s:Label x="656" y="88" text="Labor Charge"/>
    <s:Label x="849" y="86" text="Extra Person Charge"/>
    <s:Label x="636" y="162" text="Special Equipment"/>
    <s:TextInput id="input6" softKeyboardType="number" x="847" y="178" change="inputChangeHandler(event)" width="154"/>
    <s:Label x="867" y="160" text="Storage Charge"/>
    <s:Label x="815" y="311" fontSize="19" fontWeight="bold" text="Total"/>
    <s:TextInput softKeyboardType="number" x="262" y="106" width="320"/>
    <s:Label x="265" y="89" text="Credit Card Number"/>
    <s:Label x="422" y="159" text="Expiry Date"/>
    <s:TextArea id="datepicker" x="418" y="182" width="139" height="38"/>
    <s:DateSpinner x="491" y="252"/>
    <s:TextInput id="location" x="22" y="107" width="205" editable="false" enabled="true"
                 focusIn="callout.open(this.location,true)" text="Select..."/>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here-
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb702fbebf5a1312e95e4e3-8000.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DateSpinner.html

You can add date picker to your Mobile application even though its not mobile optimized by adding mx.swc to your project. That should give you access to the picker.. why not use spinner? I see that you have it in your code..